# html list add and remove using and js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple list using html input box and js. the list are creating on clicking "add skill" and get removed when click on "remove". But when I try to add some skill after remove, the last removed item also get back.

```js
   var skillList="";
   var i = 0;
   function addSkill(){
    var skills= document.getElementById("addSkill").value;
    if(skills != ""){
     skillList += "<li><span name='skillItem' id='skillItem"+ i +"'>" + skills + "</span> " +
     "<a onclick='removeSkill()'>remove</a></li>";
     i++;
     document.getElementById("skill").innerHTML = skillList;
     document.getElementById("addSkill").value="";    
    }
   }
   
   function removeSkill(){
    skillList="";
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#skill li"),index,tab = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
     tab.push(items[j].innerHTML);
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
     items[j].onclick = function(){
        
      index = tab.indexOf(this.innerHTML);
      items[index].parentNode.removeChild(items[index]);
      tab.splice(j,1);
     };
    }
    console.log(tab);
    for(var j=0; j<tab.length;j++){
     skillList += "<li>" + tab[j] + "</li>";
    }
   }
```

```html
<td><label>skills:</label></td>
         <td>
          <ul id="skill"></ul>
          <input type="text" name="skill" id="addSkill"/>
          <a onclick="addSkill();" value="">add skill</a>
         </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You got all lost in the loops and indexes in your `removeSkill` function and it's way easier than what you are doing - one single line of code. **No loops and no arrays are needed.**

You've also got a bunch of other styles of coding that are ancient and should be avoided.

- You don't need to use a hyperlink just because you want to give
  someone something to click on. All visible elements support a `click`
  event. Only use hyperlinks when you are actually navigating
  somewhere.
- You can't use table cells without a table.
- Don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`). Separate all your
  JavaScript from your HTML and do the event binding with
  `.addEventListener()`.
- Don't create new HTML by concatenating strings together. It becomes a
  nightmare fast and requires you to use `.innerHTML`, which has
  performance and security implications. Instead, create new DOM
  objects, configure their properties as needed and then append them
  into the document.

See the comments inline below:

```js
// Get all the element references you'll need just once:
var skillList = document.querySelector("#skillList");
var newSkill = document.querySelector("#newSkill");
var btnAddSkill = document.querySelector("input[type='button'");

// Do all of your event binding in JavaScript, not with inline HTML event attributes
btnAddSkill.addEventListener("click", addSkill);

function addSkill(){
 if(newSkill.value !== ""){
   // Don't build new HTML by concatenating strings. Create elements and configure them as objects
   var li = document.createElement("li");
   li.textContent = newSkill.value;
   
   // Only use hyperlinks for navigation, not to have something to click on. Any element can be clicked
   var span = document.createElement("span");
   span.classList.add("remove");
   span.textContent = "remove skill";
   span.addEventListener("click", removeSkill);  
   li.appendChild(span);  // Add the span to the bullet
   skillList.appendChild(li); // Add the bullet to the list
   newSkill.value = ""; 
 }
}
   
function removeSkill(){
  // Just remove the closest <li> ancestor to the <span> that got clicked
  skillList.removeChild(this.closest("li"));
}
```

```css
.remove { display:inline-block; margin-left:10px; padding:2px 4px; background:rgba(200,0,225,.7); color:#ff0; cursor:pointer; }

li {margin:8px 0; border-bottom:1px dashed #e0e0e0; }
```

```html
<h1>Skills:</h1>
<input type="text" name="skill" id="newSkill">
<input type="button" value="add skill">

<ul id="skillList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this piece of code

```
                for(var j=0; j<tab.length;j++){
                skillList += "<li>" + tab[j] + "</li>";
            }
```

Your were adding it again... 
Working now...

```js
var skillList="";
   var i = 0;
   function addSkill(){
    var skills= document.getElementById("addSkill").value;
    if(skills != ""){
     skillList += "<li><span name='skillItem' id='skillItem"+ i +"'>" + skills + "</span> " +
     "<a onclick='removeSkill()'>remove</a></li>";
     i++;
     document.getElementById("skill").innerHTML = skillList;
     document.getElementById("addSkill").value="";    
    }
   }
   
   function removeSkill(){
    skillList="";
    var items = document.querySelectorAll("#skill li"),index,tab = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
     tab.push(items[j].innerHTML);
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++){
     items[j].onclick = function(){
        
      index = tab.indexOf(this.innerHTML);
      items[index].parentNode.removeChild(items[index]);
      tab.pop(j,1);
     };
    }
    

   }
```

```html
<td><label>skills:</label></td>
         <td>
          <ul id="skill"></ul>
          <input type="text" name="skill" id="addSkill"/>
          <a onclick="addSkill();" value="">add skill</a>
         </td>
```

Comment: But on that case when I try to add again the previous list is totally erased.